# get key values pair from an array of objects and place in new array

Tags: reactjs

I need to keep     `{ label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry"}`, for this code to work with
the  in react though when submitting to the database i would like to have the selected values sent through as `strawberry: true, watermelon: true, pear: true,`

```
const options = [
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry"},
    { label: "Watermelon ", value: "watermelon" },
    { label: "Pear ", value: "pear" },
]
```

I would like to convert the above array to an array of

```
const newArray = [
strawberry: true
watermelon: true
pear: true
]
```

I would have a clue how you would do it maybe it's a two step thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean an *object* `{strawberry: true, watermelon: true, pear: true}` (an associative array), not an Array,

```
const options = [
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry"},
    { label: "Watermelon ", value: "watermelon" },
    { label: "Pear ", value: "pear" },
];
const optionsObject = {};
options.forEach(({value}) => optionsObject[value] = true);
```

(You can also do this with `.reduce` if you really want to:)

```
const optionsObject = options.reduce((obj, {value}) => {
  obj[value] = true;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: thanks, you most have been coding for 20 years to know this lol